# applying Amdahl’s and Gustafson’s law on matrix vector multiply

Tags: parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, mpi, openmp

I read about these laws on many threads here but still could not figure out how to apply their formulas on matrix vector multiply(y = y+ Ax). here I will try to explain my algorithm with respect to time:

> T1(sequential): processor zero generates vectors y and x and broadcast
>   them.    T2(parallel):matrix size(n) is divided among processors and
>   each marix generates its on portion and does the multiplication.
>        All processors then send results to processor zero.
>           T3(sequential):processor zero collects results, orders them and print results.

If I run this multiple times with different matrix sizes and processors. how can I apply Amdahl’s and Gustafson’s law on the results

Comment: Matrix times vector is memory bandwidth bound so it might not be the best case. Matrix times matrix is generally not memory bandwidth bound. On multi-core systems (e.g with 4 cores) matrix*matrix often get's 90% to 100% of the peak flops but on many cores (Xeon Phi  or GPUS) systems the efficient is much less than 90% (at least on KNL) so that's probably a better case.

Comment: Thank you ... I do not care of the performance now .. I just want to apply the laws on the algorithm

Comment: My point is your plots will be more interesting if you actually have some significant scaling. It would be interesting to compare the plots for matrix times vector and matrix times matrix.

Comment: This feels a lot like homework. Where are you struggling when you apply the laws to the problem? How far did you come on your own?